No internet after connecting to Proton VPN via WireGuard on Raspberry OS
My problem is that after connecting to Proton VPN via WireGuard on Raspberry OS, there is no internet access. Traffic is sent, but nothing is received.
Current Description:
Operating System: Debian 12 (Bookworm).
Network Interface: wlan1 is used for internet connection.
VPN Service: Proton VPN using WireGuard.
Problem:
After connecting to the Proton VPN server via WireGuard, there is no internet access.
Traffic is sent to the server: 1.01 KiB sent, but nothing is received (0 B received).
Ping fails:
To external IPs (e.g., 8.8.8.8).
To the internal IP of the WireGuard server (10.2.0.1).
The WireGuard client configuration is correct, but the default route through the WireGuard interface is not added automatically and must be added manually.
WireGuard Client Configuration:

[Interface]
PrivateKey = <скрыт>
Address = 10.2.0.2/32
MTU = 1420
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan1 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o wlan1 -j MASQUERADE
DNS = 10.2.0.1
[Peer]
PublicKey = ExWwfvm2QK3oJhrz4s0tsBLt1PVBiONhljwh5jt40Bk=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 185.182.193.108:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25

Symptoms:
Routes (ip route) before connecting to WireGuard:

default via 192.168.110.1 dev wlan1 proto dhcp src 192.168.110.35 metric 600
10.0.50.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.50.1 metric 100
192.168.110.0/24 dev wlan1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.110.35 metric 600

Routes (ip route) after connecting to WireGuard and manually adding the default route:

default dev wireguardclient scope link
default via 192.168.110.1 dev wlan1 proto dhcp src 192.168.110.35 metric 600
10.0.50.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.50.1 metric 100
192.168.110.0/24 dev wlan1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.110.35 metric 600

The default route through the WireGuard interface (default dev wireguardclient) is not added automatically, so it has to be added manually:

sudo ip route add default dev wireguardclient

Command wg show:

plaintext
Копировать код
interface: wireguardclient
public key: fVM4Pv55eZhqe8Hg7phS8KFCYzhcZ2dncdWuv1VBh2s=
private key: (hidden)
listening port: 35549
fwmark: 0xca6c
peer: ExWwfvm2QK3oJhrz4s0tsBLt1PVBiONhljwh5jt40Bk=
endpoint: 185.182.193.108:51820
allowed ips: 0.0.0.0/0
transfer: 0 B received, 1.01 KiB sent

Ping fails:

ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6140ms
ping 10.2.0.1
PING 10.2.0.1 (10.2.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
10.2.0.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3003ms

What Has Been Checked:
The WireGuard server is working correctly.
Internet through wlan1 works fine before connecting to WireGuard.
DNS is configured: /etc/resolv.conf contains valid DNS servers (10.2.0.1, 192.168.110.35, 8.8.8.8).
What Is Needed:
Why is the default route through WireGuard not added automatically?
Why does the client send data but receive nothing in response?
How can I fix the lack of internet access after connecting to WireGuard?
